# window.setInterval - more than expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you guys explain more deeply window.setInterval functionality? I've been asked myself several questions while running that snippet:

```
var i = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){  
   $('#show').html($('.questions :eq('+i+')'));  
}, 1000);
```

So, i think that window.setInterval is awesome because it automatically increment `i` var, displays all divs that nested in `.questions` before goes new iteration, and stops when last div in `.questions` is reached.

But the main question if it is possible to change function from outside, for example remove `$('.questions :eq('2')')`, before new iteration?

thanks!

Comment: To remove interval, you can use clearInterval function. Learn more at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, you want to rewrite the function in between intervals? No, as far as I know, that's not possible. You would have to `clearInterval` the old function, and add a new one.

The easiest way would be to modify your function so it listens to outside parameters, and behaves according to how they are set.